# Sweet alert 2 predefine content instead of using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Is there any way to have sweet alert feed off a pre-defined div or anything similar?

Basically I want to create a sweet alert modal that contacts a lot of information gathered from a DB, but i'd like to see if there is any way other than AJAX to fetch the data?

For example, I'm writing a Laravel application, is there any way to pre-write a div with blade and all of my content, then have sweet alert just copy the div when it opens and display it inside one of its modals?

Sweet alert 2 documentation [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have come up with a simple solutions myself, but i'm still open to other ideas?

I've simply created a div in blade with all the content I want, and wrapped it inside a div i've called `.sweetalert_template` like so

```
<div class="sweetalert_template">
   <span id="all_contacts">
     @foreach($user->contacts as $contact)
       <h4>{{$contact->name}}</h4>
       <p>{{$contact->telephone}}</p>
     @endforeach
   </span>
</div>
```

I'm then hiding any sweet alert templates across the whole application like this

```
.sweetalert_template {
  position:fixed;
  top:5000px;
  left:5000px;
  visibility:hidden;
  display:none;
  z-index:-9999;
}
```

And then just grabbing the html when the alert loads.

```
swal({
    title: 'User Contacts',
    html: $('.sweetalert_template #all_contacts').html(),
    customClass: 'swal-logout',
    showCloseButton: true,
});
```

It's a fairly simple way of achieving my goal, and it cuts out the extra unnecessary AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typical case for ajax - but if you really want to output all contacts with the website, you could try to put the data into an array of objects:

```
<script>
    // prepare the object array on server side
    var all_contacts = [
        @foreach($user->contacts as $contact)
            {name:"{{$contact->name}}", phone:"{{$contact->phone}}", email:"{{$contact->email}}"},
        @endforeach
    ];
    function showInfo(idx) {
        swal({
            type: 'info',
            title: 'Contact Information',
            html: all_contacts[idx].name + "<br/>" + all_contacts[idx].phone + "<br/>" + all_contacts[idx].email,
        })
    }
</script>

@foreach($user->contacts as $idx=>$contact)
   <span>{{$contact->name}}</span> <button onClick="showInfo({{$idx}})">More Info</button>
@endforeach
```

So in the first loop (within the script tag) you fill your array variable, and with the second loop you show the table with the "more info" button. 
This is a very basic example - in the end you will have to take care about escaping characters which break your variable in the first loop, and characters which might break the html output in the swal window.

Comment: I like your idea, but I think the way i'm currently doing it is easier :) I can build it all completely normally in my blade file then just grab the html. Thanks for your suggestion though.